# how to read out a value from serialized array stored in a txt-document? php

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I just started to do some simple things with php. Now i have a question… 
In this code i open a txt-file and write a key-value-array into it. 
At the end I want to read out one value from this array which is stored serialized in the txt-document.

```
$open = fopen("write/doc.txt", 'w+');
$content = array ("red" => "FF0000", "green" => "#00FF00", "blue" => "#0000FF");
$contentserialized = serialize($content);

fwrite($open, $contentserialized);

fclose($open);
```

So until now all works properly. And with this code i can show the content of the file:

```
$file = file_get_contents("write/doc.txt");
echo $file;
```

But I want only one value out of it. How can I choose for example the value for key "green" on the page?
Would be nice if you can tell me!

Comment: Do you need [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo unserialize($file)['green'];
```

or if that doesn't work(my php is a little rusty)

```
$array = unserialize($file);
echo $array['green'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You could load the entire document and parse the content back into a PHP array. That would allow you to work with the data as any other arrays. Something like the following should be enough.

```
$file = 'write/doc.txt';
$fhandle = fopen($file, 'r');
$content = fread($fhandle, filesize($file));

$content = unserialize($content);

echo $content['green'];
```

Just as a good practice, remember to close the file handle.

```
fclose($fhandle);
```

Hope this helps.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php